# Installing Rails 5.1.4 on RHEL 7.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rhel

I am trying to install Rails 5.1.4 on a RHEL 7.3 server. Ruby version 2.4.2 is installed on the node along with OpenSSL 1.0.2 .

While install rails I am getting the below error.

```
# gem install rails
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-
2.4.2@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": 
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so) - 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-
2.4.2@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": 
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so) - 
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so) - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
#


# rvm list
rvm rubies
* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.4.2 [ x86_64 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

I have updated the OpenSSL version to try to fix it but the error did not change.

Also updated to Ruby 2.4.2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to install the respective `-devel` library, should be smth like `sudo yum install libopenssl-devel`.

Comment: There were no available packages listed for `devel` for OpenSSL 1.0.2 in my system. Wasn't able to find any online also for RHEL 7.3

Comment: That’s kinda surprising, since `rpmfind` lists a lot http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=openssl-devel.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. That worked smoothly. I just installed the appropriate `devel` for the fedora version instead of the one for RHEL 7.3 and it fine after that. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Welcome. If you are running the redhat distro constantly, I would suggest you file a bug in their bugtracker. This library should be included.